# How to deal with negative Shapley coalitions/contributions

Tags: game-theory

I have a moderate understanding around the Shapley value/theorem (I've been digging into many papers and research articles lately).

I'm trying to derive weights/attribution for each player when they combine to "play" a game together and gain points.

The issue I've uncovered (with certain coalitions or permeated groupings) is that some players have a negative/drag effect on the team...In other words, their final Shapley weight/value (when computed from previous groupings) is a net negative... Example (each players points & combinations):

```
Game Types & Results
-------------------------------------
[single]   [double]      [triple]
A = 8      AB = 0        ABC = 6    Question....
B = 2      AC = 12                   find out how much percentage of credit
C = 9      CB = 1                    should be given out to each player in
                                     game of ABC = 6

Answer....
SHAPLEY WEIGHTS (with negative allowed)
---------------------------------------
A =  + 63.9%
B =  - 55.6%   <--- do I steal B's money? (joking, but not sure)
C =  + 91.7%

SHAPLEY WEIGHTS (with negatives as zero, with opt-outs)
---------------------------------------
A =  + 40.0%
B =  +  8.0%
C =  + 52.0%
```

**(Question #1)** I've read some material (I'll try to link the PDF later) that stated you can choose to "opt-out" negative coalitions during the calculation of the Shapley value--- in other words, you skip the calculation for  (instead of negative contribution, just give it zero)...Is this correct or do I have it all wrong?

**(Question #2)** If I allow for a negative Shapley value (for a player, while I'm calculating everything), could I instead give them just 0% in the final output and then scale the weights proportionally to the other players?  How should I most appropriately approach the most "fair" solution... I can't "steal" persons B's money (that doesn't seem cool)

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks again!